# "storage" event fired on the same tab in firefox

Tags: javascript, local-storage

In 2013 I wrote a piece of code that prevents a user to open a second browser tab on the same domain and it worked nicely until a year ago. It is based on the "storage" event that is supposed to be triggered when a second window write into the localStorage. This is the code:

```
$(function(){

    var this_tab_key =  randomString(30);
    var listener = function(e){

        if(e.key=='test_block' && e.newValue != this_tab_key)
        {
            STOP_AJAX_CALLS = true;
            var div = $('<div id="modal_block" style="top:0px;left:0px;position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.5;background-color:black;z-index:12000"></div>');
            div.append('<div style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:0;width:100%;font-size:60px;margin-top:-50px;text-align:center;line-height:50px;" >Please close this tab/windows <br>as another one has been opened</div>');
            $("body").append(div);
            if (window.removeEventListener) 
                window.removeEventListener("storage", listener);
            else
                window.detachEvent("onstorage", listener);
        }
    };

    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("storage", listener);
    else
        window.attachEvent("onstorage", listener);

    localStorage.setItem('test_block', this_tab_key);
});
```

What happens recently is that the "storage" event is triggered even if I have only a tab open, not always, and it happens normally after 3/5 minutes after I have opened the tab. There are not ajax/ws calls, no activity in general in the site. There are no iframe in the page so no other 'window' object.
It seems to happen only in firefox, but they told me it could happen also in chrome even if I never saw it personally.
Do you have a hint of what is happing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey @Massimo Paon, were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue now. Thanks.